# Removing all multiline junk from string?

Tags: python, string

I want to remove every markdown related thing from a string.

This is an example:

```
>EU

>Please spread this like the plague.
```

This is the single-line output that I'd like: `EU. Please spread this like the plague.`

Any  idea on how I could do this?

I already tried `.rstrip()` and `.replace('\n', '') although it doesn't do anything.

Maybe I should convert the string into html markdown and then use the available utilities to remove it? (spoiler: I have no idea how to convert a string to markdown html)

I also need to write this to a csv. This is the sample I've posted before (with both `rstrip` and `replace` applied).

```
>EU\
\
>Please spread this like the plague.\
\
<emoticon>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s = """>EU
       >Please spread this like the plague.
       """

print(' '.join(s.replace('>','').replace('.','').replace('\n','.').split()))

Out[ ]:
EU. Please spread this like the plague.
```

Note, that this required I manually remove the blank lines.

Another way to go would be to use regular expressions.

```
import re
s = re.sub(r">", '', s)
s = re.sub(r" {2}", '', s)
s = re.sub(r"\.", '', s)
s = re.sub(r"\n\n", '.', s)
s = re.sub(r" \n", '', s)
s = re.sub(r"\n", '.', s)
print(s)

Out[ ]:
EU. Please spread this like the plague.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `str.replace()`

**Ex:**

```
s = """>EU

>Please spread this like the plague.

"""

print( s.replace('\r', ' ').replace('\n', ' ') )
```

**Output:**

```
>EU  >Please spread this like the plague.
```

Comment: The output you listed is different from what the OP requested.

Comment: This partially works. First, this kills spacing between words from one line to the next (end word of first line fuses with first word of second line). Second, when writing to csv, the last word of the first line gets an ``\`` at the end and the space becomes an ``\`` (I've edited the post to add a sample).

Comment: @A.Dandelion. Have you added the space just like in the ans `replace('\r', 'SingleSpace')` ?

Comment: Nope, the problem seems to be using `csv.writer(...)` to write things into the csv. For some reason it escapes those characters.

Comment: This seems to be a better output:  `s.replace('>', ' ').replace('\n\n', '. ')`